Sprite with shader material does not react to onclick event
With three and @react-three I have a component with sprite as follow:
export function Point({ position = [0, 0, 0] }: { position?: [number, number, number] }) {
  const spriteRef = useRef<THREE.Sprite>(null)
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false)

  useCursor(hovered)

  useFrame(({ camera, clock }) => {
    spriteRef.current?.lookAt(camera.position);

    const scale = 0.1 + (1 + Math.sin(clock.getElapsedTime() * 5)) * 0.01;
    spriteRef.current!.scale.set(scale, scale, scale)
  })

  const onClick = () => alert('You clicked me!')

  return (
    <sprite ref={spriteRef} onClick={onClick} onPointerOver={() => setHovered(true)} onPointerOut={() => setHovered(false)} position={position}>
      <spriteMaterial attach="material" color={'hotpink'} />
    </sprite>
  )
}

Now here everything works perfectly, but the sprite is just pink square. I would like to add to it some shader to make it more attractive. So I changed it to:
export function Point({ position = [0, 0, 0] }: { position?: [number, number, number] }) {
  const spriteRef = useRef<THREE.Sprite>(null)
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false)

  useCursor(hovered)

  useFrame(({ camera, clock }) => {
    spriteRef.current?.lookAt(camera.position);

    const scale = 0.1 + (1 + Math.sin(clock.getElapsedTime() * 5)) * 0.01;
    spriteRef.current!.scale.set(scale, scale, scale)
  })

  const onClick = () => alert('You clicked me!')

  return (
    <sprite ref={spriteRef} onClick={onClick} onPointerOver={() => setHovered(true)} onPointerOut={() => setHovered(false)} position={position}>
      {/* <spriteMaterial attach="material" color={'hotpink'} /> */}
      <shaderMaterial 
        attach="material"
        transparent={true}
        depthWrite={false}
        uniforms={{
          color: { value: new THREE.Color("hotpink") },
        }}
        vertexShader={`
          varying vec2 vUv;
          void main() {
            vUv = uv;
            vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
            gl_PointSize = 300.0 / -mvPosition.z;
          }
        `}
        fragmentShader={`
          uniform vec3 color;
          varying vec2 vUv;
          void main() {
            float dist = length(vUv - vec2(0.5)); 
            float alpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(0.3, 0.5, dist);
            gl_FragColor = vec4(color, alpha);
          }
        `}
      />
    </sprite>
  )
}

But at this point ononClick, onPointerOver and onPointerOut do not work anymore. Would any one be able to advice me what should I change to have it working not only with sprite material but also with shader material?

I don't know if you are not willing to use drie, but I was always using their helper (the one called shaderMaterial) and that worked just fine for me in the past. I haven't tested it, but that may be an option!
